# data input to javascript on htm webpage

Tags: javascript, bash, curl, html

Coding languages are not my forte so please excuse anything ignorant that I say.

I need to input data into a webpage that runs a javascript to analyse the data I provide... the problem is I have several hundred individuals and the webpage only works one individual at a time.
here is the page
http://www.hprg.com/hapest5/hapest5b/hapest5.htm

How could I use the terminal (or anything else) to iteratively upload each set of data to the page and retrieve the results.

I've tried curl and wget as per this...
https://journalxtra.com/linux/bash-linuxsanity/bash-filling-web-forms-with-curl-and-wget/
... using formfind & wget/curl but I think it doesn't work with javascript input.

Here is an example of the desired input.

Input string: 13,21,15,11,0,0,0,0,11,13,11,30,16,0,0,0,0,0,14,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,0,0,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

No Extra Alleles; Separator=Comma

I'm using an iMac (late 2015) with macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a javascript that could help automate what youre trying to do at least a little bit.

```
var inputStringArray = ['13,21,15,11,0,0,0,0,11,13,11,30,16,0,0,0,0,0,14,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,0,0,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '10001', '0'];

function setInputString(newInputStr) {
    document.getElementById('haplotype').value = '';
    document.getElementById('haplotype').value = newInputStr;
}

function getResultData() {
    var rowArray = document.querySelectorAll('#results tr'),
        i, dataObj = {},
        rowNode;
    for (i = 0; i < rowArray.length; i++) {

        if (i > 0) {
            rowNode = rowArray[i].childNodes;
            dataObj[rowNode[0].innerText] = {
                fitness_score: rowNode[1].innerText,
                probability: rowNode[2].innerText
            }
        }
    }  
    return dataObj;
}

function execute(inputStringArray) {
    var i, resultData = {};

    for (i = 0; i < inputStringArray.length; i++) {
        setInputString(inputStringArray[i]);
        parse();
        resultData[inputStringArray[i]] = getResultData();
    }
    console.log(resultData);
    resultData = null;
}

execute(inputStringArray);
```

Basically the only thing you need to change in the script are the values in the 'inputStringArray'. You should enter as many input strings as you want (input strings should be surrounded single quotes and separated by comma).

Open up Google chrome and press F12 button on your keyboard to enter chrome developer tools and navigate to the 'console tab': https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/shortcuts

Once in the console screen, paste the script from below and replace the strings in the inputStringArray then press enter. You should see a javascript object printed in the console with the results you are looking for. Results will look like this:
[image: Example of formatted data]

This script is intended to run in the console for the link you provided in your question only. Feel free to edit the script however you feel appropriate.